# Poor quality on ImageView

Tags: ios, swift, camera, imageview

I find this strange, I noticed when using the front camera on my iOS which will then output the image to my UIImageView, the result has poor quality.

However, with Snapchat the quality is amazing!

Can anyone explain what Snapchat do? I've been searching everywhere yet cannot find anything useful

Comment: Did you resize your photo ? if so please put some code, otherwise maybe contentMode property of your imageView is wrong

Comment: @LoryHuz The ImageView is the same size as the screen like Snapchat.. no code has been implemented to change the design aspect of the ImageView. Also the contentMode property is Aspect Fill

Comment: There is several ways to take a photo that's why I asked you some code.. You could have used UIImagePickerController or AVFoundation.

Comment: Back in the day, front cameras were a "generation" behind the rear cameras. If that is *still* true today, then Snapchat is probably using a filter to sharpen the image. Core Image has these kind of filters.